# Nginx won't redirect http to https

Tags: nginx

I can't figure this out. Can you help?

This is my setup:

Single website on server.

Going to http://... worked fine until I added the https://... settings to my site config.

Going to https://... now works fine.

Going to http://... now just times out.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mywebsite.io www.mywebsite.io;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name mywebsite.io www.mywebsite.io;
        root /var/www/mywebsite.io/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cert_chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/mywebsite.key;
}
```

Am I doing something stupid?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mywebsite.io www.mywebsite.io;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

As `$server_name` is ambiguous when you have more than one.

Comment: I fixed the problem. It seems an update blocked port 80. Insane. I've re-opened the port now.